# Doxygen - overridden method - the comment is not inherited, why?

Tags: php, doxygen

I have two classes in PHP: `Figure` and `Circle`. `Circle` extends `Figure`. `Figure` has a method `draw()`. `Circle` inherits this method and overrides it.

The `draw()` method is commented in the parent class, but it does not have a comment in the `Circle` class as it shall inherit it.

```
/**
 * Description of Figure  
 *
 * @author admin
 */
class Figure{

    /**
     * Does something
     */
    public function draw() {

    }
}

/**
 * Description of Circle  
 *
 * @author admin
 */
class Circle extends Figure{


    public function draw() {
        //overriden method
    }
}
```

Doxygen says:
"warning: Member draw() (function) of class Circle is not documented."

How to make Doxygen put in the inherited comment?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using (current version is 1.8.11)? can you give a small code example to show the problem?

Comment: Yes, I use 1.8.11 version.

Answer (score 6):

You need to tell doxygen where to take the documentation from, using [`@copydoc` annotation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc).

```
/**
 * Description of Circle  
 *
 * @author admin
 */
class Circle extends Figure {

    /**
     * @copydoc Figure::draw()
     */
    public function draw() {
        //overriden method
    }
}
```

Inside the documentation block below `@copydoc` you can add more documentation, like for example why the method is overridden.